# Is send() guaranteed on non-blocking socket after calling close()?

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, netty

I noticed that if using `channel.writeAndFlush(byteBuf).addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE)` in Netty, the expected operation would be message sent before channel was closed. My question is that when apply to the operating system's API, is calling send() guaranteed to send the data to the remote before calling close() when using a non-blocking socket?

Comment: The operating system will *attempt* to send everything pending before the final FIN induced by the `close()`. However if it can't, `close()` being asynchronous, it has no way of telling you that it failed. That, and only that, is what `SO_LINGER` is for: to provide a close timeout, which trips if it can't send the pending data.